# Javascript referencing approach

Tags: javascript, dojo

In my past projects I used to create a javascript app object and create references to dom and dijit nodes. Some time ago I read that this leads to problems with garbage collection, since js keeps a reference to dom (or something on these lines)

```
app = {
        // UI - divs
    _divMainView : null,
    _divCurrent : null,
    _divTmSelectContianer : null,
    _divSpSelectContianer : null,
    _loadingMsg : null,
    _loadingOverlay : null,

    // tabs
    _tabs : null,
    _tab1 : null,
    _tab2 : null,

    init : function() {     },
    _initUi : function() { 
        dojo.parser.parse();
                this._divMainView = dojo.byId('main');
                this._tab2 = dijit.byId('tab1');
                // wire up events
        },
    _handleEvent : function() {},
    _doSomething : function() {}
}
```

What I liked about the way I used to do things, is that the node 'id' is only referenced once in the code.

So what's the alternative? using dojo.ById() and dijit.byId() every time I need a domNode / dijit widget? Only maintainable option I can think of is creating "constants" with the widget/node IDs.

Comment: Well there is no immediate problem with what you were doing before. Are you sure you understood where the problems come from?

Comment: Can't find the original article I had read, but these seem to refer to the same problem. dom circular reference.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830555

If I remember correctly this is mainly an issue with ie8 or older.

What triggered me to look up memory leaks was a browser slowdown when developing an infinite scroll data grid. memory was not being released after the grid was destroyed.

Comment: that doesn't tell anything to me except that you didn't correctly clear out references when destroying the grid

Comment: I set all references within the grid and to the grid itself to null.

Comment: Well are you using closures or adding expando properties on the dom elements? Since you are using dojo, does it do as good clean up job as jQuery for its internal event listener data etc?

Comment: yes there's expando props for each row. I'll check that out.

With regards, to closures. I'm using a dojo function called hitch.. which sets the scope for function calls. If i'm not mistaken it makes use of closures.

don't know about dojo cleaning up events

Comment: expando props that reference objects could be problematic since AFAIK chrome at least uses some kind of reference counting in DOM which famously has problems with circular references. See http://gfxprose.blogspot.fi/2013/02/debugging-resource-leak-in-webkit.html